# SPWeb.GetUserToken(x) vs SPWeb.Users[x].UserToken

Tags: permissions, runwithelevatedprivileges, token

I'm working in code to elevate an account with the Read role to a specific account with the Contribute role in order to create a list item.

I currently get the `SPUserToken` for the contribution account by reading

```
web.Users[actName].UserToken
```

and I was suprised to note that this works as long as you have the Read role on the web. (This means I don't need to open the web in a `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` block just to get the token - brilliant!)

However, if alternatively I try to use

```
web.GetUserToken(actName)
```

then I am denied access - because the Read role doesn't have the Enumerate Permissions permission. Microsoft have explicitly checked for that permission before returning the token.

I am rather worried by the fact that Microsoft have seen fit to block off one way of getting the token, but not the other. The documentation for `GetUserToken` does *say* it checks permissions, but I'd expect any other method of getting the token to make such a check too.

Can anyone tell me if there's a good reason for this difference?

Comment: Coherence? Since the rest of it is bugged, why should this follow common sense? Just joking... anyway, good point in finding this, +1 for the question. Now we only need someone to find an answer. If I should make a bet, I would say that they use the first method somewhere in the code in a context where the check isn't appropriate or could lead to problem, so that in the end they had to live with it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to impersonate a different user? Or just temporarily need permission to write to a resource?

These scenarios are covered here: http://www.schaeflein.net/impersonation-and-elevation-of-privilege/

Comment: I'm doing this in order to create a list item in a list which the user can see but not contribute to. I want to use an account that is specifically for creating these items, not elevate to the all-powerful site collection admin account.

Comment: Then you need to get that account token while that user is logged on. Or you need to know that account's credentials. Or you have to use the SystemAccount (which is the recommendation).

Comment: Nope. I've successfully got the token without the user being logged on, without knowing the credentials, and without escalating to the system account. I can do this by calling `web.Users[x].UserToken` on a web on which I have Read permissions, as I've said in the question.

Comment: I would suggest that since it does not work in all scenarios, you do *not* successfully have the token. The approach documented in my article has been validated by the product group and is in use in countless farms.

Comment: In that case, something even worse is going on, because Sharepoint is letting a user with Read permissions create list items without even successfully having the token.